# How to display JasperReports Viewer inside a JPanel/JFrame..?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I'm a newbie in using `JasperReports`. In my `Swing` application I want to show `JRViewer` inside a `JPanel` or `JFrame`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
JRDataSource dataSource = ...;

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("id", 42);

JasperReport report = (JasperReport) 
        JRLoader.loadObject("c:/reports/report.jasper");

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, dataSource);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Report");
frame.getContentPane().add(new JRViewer(jasperPrint));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `JRViewer` class is a subclass of `javax.swing.JPanel`, so treat it like a normal `JPanel` and do your stuff.