# Best way to go for taking up fat clients in Java desktop apps

Tags: java, swing, gwt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I mostly work in the server side but I have developed desktop apps in Swing.
I want to make a "fat" desktop application for management of a small office that needs to incorporate the ability to print and display neet reports from data from a Database.
My question is the following:
I have read that BIRT is the way to go when it comes to reporting, but it is not clear to me if I can integrate it in a swing application so that I can reuse my knowledege.
So if it is not possible and have to invest time to other technology what should I go for?
RCP or GWT or what? (I only know Swing. No other client side UI framework)
I hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reporting, I would choose [JasperReports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports) from JasperSoft. It has an open source community version and commercial support is available. They have a [visual report designer](http://www.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer) as well.

If one of the purposes of the reports is to be printed, the best option is to have a PDF version of the report. In that case, I'm not sure why you don't go with a web site that displays HTML reports and offers PDF-download links for printing.

Of course you can do that in a Swing application as well. For displaying a Jasper report in a Swing application see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059636/display-jasper-viewer-inside-a-jpanel-jframe).

Comment: So you think it should be better to look into a web client instead?

Comment: If that's what you know best, then yes.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the application is not that big as far as the expectations/requirements are concerned.Small data and the biggest thing is the reporting.So I am trying to do something minimal so that the installation is minimal.I.e. I use Jetty as embedded and not Tomcat, so no web app deployment just HTTP/XML process and store in the DB. Not sure if the HTML reports (since the report is what is expected) will be better than a full fledged framework like `jasper` that you propose.

Comment: I was proposing to use jasper for the web client, too. But if you're bundling the web container, you could just as well write a Swing application.