# best way to display reports in netbeans gui

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i have menu item (NetBeans) that when pressed needs to generate a report on a linux machine. Do you have any idea on what would be th ebest way to display the form should i

1. Use iReport and Jasper Reports
2. Display the information in some sort of jdialogue form that pops up once the menu item is selected.

The way i produce the report might be insufficient. I use a c-shell script to read the call a sql script to read the information from the database and then dump it into a txt file. I want to read this text file and produce an offical report either using ireport or on a jdialue form. From reviewing ireport it seems like i dont have to use this method. I can run the sql script directly from ireport and generate the rpeort? problem is i am on a linux machine and im not sure ireports will work well plus this will be a long term effort to build a desktop gui and im wondering if this is the right apporach . Does iReport have reliable support and will it work with the latest netbeans releasde? anyone with experience may answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper Reports is cross platform, iReport is built on the Netbeans platform. I have used iReport/JasperReports on OS X and Windows personally and it works great. I have used Netbeans on Linux, and it worked great. iReport should work just as well on Linux as the other platforms it supports. Another option iReport supports is run it as a plugin inside Netbeans, which works very well.

Yes iReport and Jasper Reports are reliable in general. I am not sure what you mean by support though. They have commercial versions to provide actual support, everything else is forums and/or here from other users.

As far as the process you were thinking of doing, parsing the text file and all, I would not suggest that. Jasper Reports allows you to place the query in the actual report. It will be quicker and much easier to work with than a multiple step process like you are talking about.

**2) Display the information in some sort of jdialogue form that pops up once the menu item is selected.**

I have no clue what you are asking here.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I was asking if there is a jcomponent that can display a report in swing or should i just use ireport and jasper

Comment: and this might be off topic but nobody has helped me. are you familiar with netbeans jtable tablemodel and updating rows from a jtable and having the database reflect these changes? i see you have java background

Comment: Actually there is a component you can use. Take a look at [How to display JasperReports Viewer inside a JPanel/JFrame..?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3059636/3340) for how to use it.

Comment: This is not going to really answer you question, but is a good tip for asking questions around here. Break you question up. For the JTable part. You obviously have an editable table already. What you are really trying to ask is "How do I know what rows have been changed in a JTable?". Once you know what rows need to be updated, if needed you could ask "How do I run a SQL Query to update a database table row?". Basically small bite size chunks that people can process easily. When ever possible make a small example in code.

Comment: You do not want to include a wall of code, as that intimidates people. But make a very very small runnable example people can work with. You will be amazed at how quick you get help when you do these things. So make sure your question is very clear and specific and provide an example with code.